# Should a failed login attempt result in a http 401 response

Tags: authentication, http-status-code-401

Should a failed login attempt result in a HTTP 401 response? Doesn't seem like all the major sites do this.

Comment: I had no idea there's a tag for 401, wow

Comment: @prusswan there shouldn't be, it's ridiculous.

Comment: @MK well, at least there were a 100 over uses of it (anyway I did not add it just in case of misunderstanding!)

Comment: I would go and remove them all one by one if I had time.  The overly specific tags do not add any value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it depends on the type of authentication in use.

If you look at the [same source that @Jan Vorcak cited](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (RFC 2616), it says that the 401 response "MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource."  That refers (as has been posted since I started typing this answer) to the HTTP authentication schemes based on [RFC 2617](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html).  Few sites intended for the general public use seem to use these authentication methods anymore.  So, since the WWW-Authenticate header is meaningless, it should not be included, which means that returning a 401 error violates RFC 2616.

So, in most cases, I think the answer is "no."

Answer (score 3):

Only if your site uses HTTP-code based authentication schemes like the basic authentication or digest authentication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

There are other obvious alternatives, like relying on custom cookies and using 302 to redirect to a login page. The 302-based authentication schemes are probably used most often.